# Vim: Autocmds not triggered after .vimrc cleanup

Tags: vim

In order to work out why a certain autocmd used for new Java source files wasn't triggered, I decided to clean up my .vimrc and my .vim/ftplugin/java.vim. This has caused
all of my Java related autocmds not to get triggered.  Eg. I can't compile any longer with `:make`. Can someone tell me what I have botched up in my .vimrc below ? I have added my java.vim too.

.vimrc:

```
set nocompatible
set bs=2
set tw=72
set cindent
set mouse=a
set nowrapscan
set showmatch
set showmode
set uc=0
map ^H X
map \e[3~ x
set mousehide
set hlsearch
let c_comment_strings=1

" Color for xiterm, rxvt, nxterm, color-xterm :
if has("terminfo")
set t_Co=8
set t_Sf=\e[3%p1%dm
set t_Sb=\e[4%p1%dm
else
set t_Co=8
set t_Sf=\e[3%dm
set t_Sb=\e[4%dm
endif

"Appearences
colorscheme wombat256 
set t_Co=256

set path+=.

syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

map gf <C-W>f
set number
set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*

"Typo/spelling abbreviations
ab weigth weight
```

java.vim:

```
set shiftwidth=4
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.java set textwidth=80
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.java set makeprg=javac\ %
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.java set errorformat=%A%f:%l:\ %m,%+Z%p^,%+C%.%#,%-G%.%#
au BufRead *.java set include=^\s*import 
au BufRead *.java set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'\\.','/','g')

"Add some boiler plate
au! BufNewFile *.java
\ exe "normal O/*\r" . expand('%:t') . "\t" . strftime("%B %d %Y") .
\ "\r/\r\rpublic class " . expand('%:t:r') . " {\r\t" |
\ startinsert!

"Abbreviations
ab psvm  public static void main(String[] args) {<ESC>o
ab sopl  System.out.println();<ESC>hi
ab sepl  System.error.println();<ESC>hi
ab fori  for (int i = 0; i <; i++) {<ESC>7hi
```

Edit: When I open a file with .java extension, and do `set filetype?` I do get `filetype=java`, but none of the `au`s get triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move your java.vim to ~/.vim/ftplugin/**java**/java.vim.

You don't need to put the settings in java.vim behind an 'au' filter. The whole file will be sourced for java files.

e.g. in my .vim/ftplugin/java/java.vim I have lines like:

```
setlocal textwidth=120 wm=120 smartindent expandtab softtabstop=4

" Compile maven
nmap <F5> :!mvn compile<cr>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Side note**: As werkshy pointed it out, all your definitions should go into an java-ftplugin, which shall be autocommand-free. And there, all the definitions shall be buffer local: e.g.

```
setlocal textwidth=80
...
ab <buffer> psvm  public static void main(String[] args) {<ESC>o
nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :make<cr>
```

**Back to your problem**: Here, the template-loading autocommand is defined too late. It has to be done into a plugin/your .vimrc. The best solution is certainly to rely on a [template-expander plugin](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aAutomated_Text_Insertion). Most of them support interpretation of viml function nowadays. This way the template will be much more easier to maintain.